# Generic HashMap with Lists and putIfAbsent

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

In Java, I want to add a getOrAdd method to a regular map, just like putIfAbsent on a ConcurrentHashMap.

Furthermore, for a certain key I want to store a list of items. Here's my attempt:

```
public class ListMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    private HashMap<K, List<V>> map;

    public ListMap() {
        map = new HashMap<K, List<V>>();
    }

    public List<V> getOrAdd(K key) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        } else {
            List<V> l = new ArrayList<V>();
            map.put(key, l);
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if someone wanted to iterate over a ListMap, he would need to cast the values explictly.

```
ListMap<Integer, MyClass> listMap = new ListMap<Integer, MyClass>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyClass> entry : listMap.entrySet()) {
    List<MyClass> val = (List<MyClass>) entry.getValue();
}
```

1. Is there a way of extending the HashMap class by some methods without creating a subclass? ( I've seen this in C#)
2. How can the ListMap class be modified such that one can get a ListMaps's value (List) without casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance of your class will be also HashMap so you don't need to, or even shouldn't add another field just to support `getOrAdd` method because other inherited and not overridden methods will not be referring to `map` field but to `this` instance.

So instead of adding separate field

```
private HashMap<K, List<V>> map;
```

change extending type of your `ListMap` to

```
public class ListMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<V>> 
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

and change your `getOrAdd` method to not use `map` field but `this`

```
public List<V> getOrAdd(K key) {
    if (containsKey(key)) {
        return get(key);
    } else {
        List<V> l = new ArrayList<V>();
        put(key, l);
        return l;
    }
}
```

This change will let you use your map like

```
ListMap<Integer, String> listMap = new ListMap<Integer, String>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : listMap.entrySet()) {
    List<String> val = entry.getValue();//NO CASTING NEEDED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just extend `HashMap` like this:

```
public class ListMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<V>> {
...
}
```